# why IntelliJ debbuging slows my entire system?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDE (2021.2.3 community) in a java project and I am not able to utilize the debug because whenever I run and it hits a breakpoint it slows my  mouse and keyboard, mainly the mouse and it becomes impossible to do anything other than struggle to end the process. That's very weird, I looked into the process manager during the issue and my system looked ok on cpu and memory

Comment: “Looked ok” means?

Comment: not using a lot of cpu and ram, plenty available

Comment: Can you reproduce this on another machine?

Comment: Do you face the issue only while debugging?

Comment: Only when it hits a breakpoint while debugging, yes

Comment: I didn't reproduce in another machine because I only have this one (I also don't have a virtual machine installed)

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) attaching logs folder (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue.

Comment: I'm gonna do that, thanks